# Hiding table cells in safari 5?

Tags: html, css, safari

What I am doing seems to work on firefox and IE but not safari.

I have something like this

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="display: none;">hi</th>
       </tr>

</thead>
<tr class="someClass">
    <td style="display: none;"><span>hi</span></td>
</tr>
```

Now imagine I have many columns and rows and many headers. Now in all browsers this coulmn would be hidden. In safari it makes some gap and then all the other columns are out of alignment.

http://gyazo.com/ef5ce5e994abb954aab7069b14699476.png

this is how my column headers look like. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you make a demonstration on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? It makes it easier for us to *fiddle* with your code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can try to set the width to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I just put that column last(and the header last as well). Now it seems to look proper.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `display:none` on an element takes it out of the document flow, but that doesn't always work well with table cells as they are not independent of the surrounding elements.

You would have to actually remove the elements from the table rather than hiding them to make the table realign itself with the remaining elements.

Comment: Well I need the data in those cells but I don't want to show them to the user. It makes it so much easier to do a jquery selector if it is in a cell. So it would be nice to get around this.